# What is the Coandă effect? How is it defined, and what causes it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

Can anybody explain to me the [Coandă effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) well? I am finding that many definitions and explanations conflict.

I am particularly confused about the following points regarding the Coandă effect:

- whether the Coandă effect is the same as normal boundary layer attachment to a surface
- whether the Coandă effect is only defined for convex surfaces over which a jet (of the same state as the surrounding fluid) is tangentially blown
- what causes the Coandă effect: the jet entraining the ambient fluid or a balance of pressure and centrifugal forces, or something else?

Comment: Try this [*terrific site*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/spins.html#sec-coanda). It discusses the Coandă effect and how it is different from the usual process by which wings produce lift.

Comment: The site wasn't technical enough, but thanks anyway. It also uses the "spoon under running water" example which I thought was dominated by surface tension rather than the Coanda effect.

Answer (score 1):

The Coanda Effect occurs rarely in nature. It always involves a fast jet sheet. Such a jet may
occur under a roof gutter for example if it is sloping so the water sheet can pick up some speed. It occurs at the underside of the inside top of the stomach after a drink because the falling water becomes a jet sheet and will flow under a surface adhereing to it. It is almost always man made.

NASA and others have been using it to increase lift up to 3 times by blowing a jet sheet from a slot to over a bluff trailing edge. This shifts the rear stagnation point to the underside and postpones stall.See "The Coanda Effect And Lift" at www.newfluidtechnology.com