# What causes the Coandă effect?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, air, aircraft, lift

What causes the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect)? Here's my understanding of it:

When a fluid flows around a curved surface it has high velocity and so low pressure its pressure will be lower than the atmospheric pressure and so it will be forced to follow the curve by the higher pressure of the atmosphere.

If this above explanation is correct then how can flowing water have a pressure lower than the atmospheric pressure doesn't water have higher  pressure than the atmosphere even if it has high velocity?

If this explanation is incorrect then please give me the right explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67036/2451

Comment: this link https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67036/2451 really doesn't answer my question

Comment: Water has higher density than air. That does not make it have higher pressure.

Comment: doesn't high density mean high pressure

Comment: No, pressure and density are completely different things.